# How to send fixed string through wifi in android

Tags: android, esp8266

im trying to send some set of commands to esp8266 module using android app. i need to send commands like FF@, SS@ etc for it to work. i need it to first connect to the modules IP and socket no 80 before sending the codes. can some one tell me how to acheive this . I am new to android programming.

Comment: how are you programming the esp8266?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/865.15/people/dan.chen/esp8266/) esp8266 accepts HTTP GET requests in form `http://192.168.X.X/?s=YYY` where YYY - your command. You can do it in clear Java, but it's much easier to use [OkHttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String runCommand(String ip, String command) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("http://" + ip + "/?s=" + command)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Make sure, that you executing this on background thread